# Python UPGRADE changed virtual VENV environment version using official installer on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows-installer, python-venv

Now this is not a duplicate question:
I installed (upgraded Python) using the Windows installer.
It gave me the "upgrade" option. So I did.
But herein lies the problem.. It has seemingly upgraded the versions inside my virtual environments created with VENV. When I run python -V inside the activated environment it shows version 3.10.8 when it should be 3.10.4 (the version I upgraded from)..

Is this normal behaviour? See installers below:
[image]

https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#virtual-environments

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, that is expected behavior. It is safe to update the maintenance version. If you had updated from `3.10.X` to `3.11.Y` (different "minor" version number), then the virtual environments would be broken, but since you updated only the "maintenace" version number it is safe.

Comment: I have been poring all over the documentation; though it is still not clearly stated..

Comment: You are probably right, I do not know where this is clearly documented. -- Anyway, once you look into the content of a virtual environment directory, you will see a directory `path/to/venv/lib/python3.10` which hints that it should work with any Python 3.10.